# Is there a way I can add field types to com_fields?

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-field

Joomla's custom fields feature is missing quite a few and important field types

Is there a way I can add field types to com_fields?

As an example, there is no "file" (https://docs.joomla.org/File_form_field_type) available (see screen capture).

[image]

Comment: If your custom field plugin is installed and activated (and has tmpl folder/file too), and the plugin is of course in plugins/fields folder, then theoretically the field type will be displayed in the type list automatically.

Comment: But before that you need to create the custom field plugin...

Comment: @Sharky - that’d be quite healthy for this too :)

Comment: You guys make me feel dumb for having placed this question. :)
It's so easy, I cannot understand why Joomla is not shipped with plugins for all the default field types. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @AlexandrePaulo - no, there is no any problem with your question. Many people can learn and get help from these questions, even if the answers look simple sometimes. Basically this is a good question, that is why I upvoted it...